# How to handle params of size 2D in OpenMDAO?

Tags: openmdao

I have a param that is a 2D array. It works fine with getting the correct output but when I try to do anything with the gradients such as optimization or check_total_derivatives I get a sizing error. I was wondering what the best way is to handle params that are of size 2D. Here is a sample code:

```
import numpy as np
from openmdao.api import Group, Problem, Component, IndepVarComp, ExecComp

class C1(Component):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super(C1, self).__init__()
        self.add_param('grid', val=np.zeros((n, n)))
        self.add_output('x', shape=1)
        self.n = n

def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
    x = 0
    for i in range(self.n):
        for j in range(self.n):
            x += params['grid'][i][j]
    unknowns['x'] = x

def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
    J = {}
    J['x', 'grid'] = np.ones((self.n, self.n))
    return J

class Group1(Group):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super(Group1, self).__init__()
        self.add('grid', IndepVarComp('grid', np.zeros((n, n))), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('c1', C1(n), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('obj_cmp', ExecComp('obj = -x', x=1.0), promotes=['*'])
n = 3
p = Problem()
p.root = Group1(n)
p.setup(check=False)
p['grid'] = np.ones((n, n))
p.run()
p.check_total_derivatives()
print p['x']
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: In component 'c1', the derivative of 'x' wrt 'grid' should have shape '(1, 3)' but has shape '(3, 3)' instead.
```

I feel like the derivative in this case should be of size (3, 3) because that is the size of the input param. How do you handle 2D params?

Comment: While there was a small mistake in the defined Jacobian here, the error msg was also incorrect. As a note, the error msg was fixed in this pull request: https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/pull/444

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a small mistake in the Jacobian; it should look like this:

```
def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
    J = {}
    J['x', 'grid'] = np.ones((1, self.n*self.n))
    return J
```

The output `x` is length 1, while the param `grid` is n by n, so it is length n*n, so the resulting J should be 1 by 9. With that change, I get the right answer.

I did notice a mistake in the error message. It should say that the expected shape is (1, 9) instead of (1, 3). I will put in a fix for that.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a 2D variable and need to construct the gradient, flatten it (in row-major order) and formulate the gradient based on the flattened version.